# How do i place an image texture over multiple objects?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image: Mixed up order]

I can make an image appear on a single face of a cube and by sharing the material, I can make a single image spread over the same side of many cubes. However the order of the images seems set at random. Is there a way of preserving the relative allocation of pieces of the image?

EDIT:

Further to SHikha Mittal's extremely good attempt, I was hoping for this result:

[image]

Comment: it depends that what are your specifications in the situation , do you want the objects to be strictly under different objects , or joining them is okay?

Comment: At this point I would be happy to see a solution - so joining would not be a restriction. I can see how having unjoined objects might make for a more complicated solution.

Comment: The rotations are not random.. they are due to the UV unwrap of each cube, which could be corrected.

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts, how does one correct the unwrap without manually shifting the squares around?

Comment: You could just rearrange the cubes.. but I guess that's what you're trying to avoid? Or @lemon's answer, and bake?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You can use the following node tree settings using *"Object"* output from *"Texture coordinates"* using another object (here an empty):

[image]

The empty will project along its Z axis.

On bottom line, the coordinates are shifted by 0.5 to center the image. The image is set to "clip".

On top line, we only keep Z values we want (upon a small negative value if the empty is placed along the objects we're projecting on). This is multiplied by alpha to render as red alpha parts of the image.

[image]

Comment: I really like this approach. It made me think about how I could use nodes and I like the idea of connecting an image to an empty. The math nodes look pretty intuitive. However, I think this is essentially projecting the image as a ray, and so there will be gaps in the image where it doesn't fall on a face of an object. I like this answer, it is a solution, but perhaps not to the problem I posed.

Comment: @kk, ok... I was thinking you wanted these gaps in the image... will try to find a way with no gaps.

Answer (score 0):

So as you stated in the comments

> At this point I would be happy to see a solution - so joining would not be a restriction

so an easy solution would be to select the 4 objects and clicking Ctrl > J to join them , make sure that one object is highlighted in yellow and other in orange , then select the 4 front faces in edit mode and go to front view and go to option UV>Project from View Bounds

Comment: I like this, it works, but I was hoping for a more programmatic or node based solution rather than one that is UI dependent. I also note that the image is put on the objects like a projector would (i guess that is in the name) and as such, parts of the image are missing where there are gaps between the objects.

Comment: @KK_ that will hapen....... , but if you want absolute result you can bring them together and tehn perform the same procedure

Comment: I want to get away from manually moving the UVmaps around - although that is what I had to do for the edited image. Is there some way using nodes, based upon the Texture Coordinates and Mapping?

Comment: @KK_ well i honestly don't think so but there might be......am not that experienced.......