# Object forming patterns

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, uv, physics

Here is my file. It's 40mb, and I saved it compressed, so I'm not sure how it will look. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X9loKHE1Mi0N3oCKVxh5Eg6KV7S6s7km/view?usp=sharing

I saw this video last night https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yrif5lXX7WY and at 4min in he says you have to unwrap an image texture and project from view. His cubes were just plain and didn't already have textures applied. So do I have to do something to the texture I already have applied, so they are permanent, and then I can overlay another texture from view. My cubes do have scratches and smudge marks on it for realism from other projects. Do I just need to remove those and if so how do I still keep the color

His cubes

[image]

My cubes

[image]

The image I want to project on the cubes

[image]

Also, when he does the project from view and selects all the cubes, you can see the same pile in the UV area. But when I do it, I only see one cube highlighted.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYL9w6xsZ6g

Comment: another option: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201185/31447

Comment: using texture atlas: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92624/31447

Comment: None of those explained what I would have to do if I already have textures applied to the cubes. There are 1001 cubes, and it's taking my laptop forever for each button click, so I'm not able to test every thing I see. But I'm just curious if doing this will mess up my colors I already have on the cubes and if it would just ignore the ones that the white logo wouldn't touch. Also, the last 2 photos, I have an issue with getting the project from view to select all the cubes in the UV mode. As you can see on left all cubes are selected but on UV mode only one is selected.

Comment: As always when it comes to simulations: Test using eg. 10 cubes, if all is working fine up-res to 1000. BTW: If you think about it, you can not have a texture already applied, it's a simulation.

Comment: That's true, and I realize that I'm not close enough to see the textures applied to the cubes so ill remove them and leave the colors and see if I can get that to work, but I'm still having an issue with the UV thing project from view. It won't show me all the cubes selected, so I can project the logo on them all.